# Repayment of Shabas expenditures

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, money

*Betza* 15-16 says that one's allotment of money for the year doesn't include expenditures for *Shabas* and *yom tov*, for which one is repaid according to his outlay. (First off, am I reading that right? But I assume so, so that's not my main question, which follows.) What's included in this?

- Expenditures for anyone (oneself, one's family, one's guests, one's hosts (bring a bottle of wine when you go for a meal), anyone at all)? Donations to [*tom'che Shabas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomchei_Shabbos)?
- Expenditures on anything (*chulent* meat, precut toilet tissue, candlesticks)?
- Rentals (tables, chairs)? Services (waiter)?
- The *Shabas* portion of stuff purchased for general use (one seventh the price of a canister of salt, or, combining with the subquestion above about non-food items and services, one seventh the price of a house or medical aide)?
- The *Shabas* portion of food cooked for *Shabas* but with leftovers eaten during the week?
- The weekday portion of food cooked for *Shabas* but with leftovers eaten during the week? What if one made extra so he'd have during leftovers for the week? Or what if none of it actually got eaten on *Shabas* (say, you forgot to serve it)?

With sources, please, where possible, of course.

Comment: The bounty notice has a typo. I *seek*, not *see*, an explicit, direct, and authoritative source.

Answer (score 4):

> The Shita Mekubetzes mentions in the
>   name of the Ritva that the "Divine
>   reimbursement" applies to expenses of
>   all mitzvos, and that Shabbos, Yom
>   Tov, and Children's Torah education
>   were chosen as examples because they
>   are common and regular.
>
> There is a parable of a wealthy man
>   who has two married children. One
>   child is very wealthy while the other
>   one is poor. The father sends out
>   invitations to the two children,
>   inviting them to come visit him in
>   honor of a third child's bar mitzvah.
>   The father asks that, in his honor,
>   they buy new clothing, and that
>   whatever they spend for this, he will
>   repay.
>
> The wealthy child spends a fortune,
>   adorning himself and his family in the
>   finest raiment, while the poor child
>   is unable even to borrow the amount
>   needed to buy the simplest of new
>   clothing. After the bar mitzvah, the
>   wealthy child presents his father with
>   a hefty bill, which the father refuses
>   to pay: "I promised to pay expenses
>   incurred in my honor," says the
>   father. "Had you been concerned with
>   my honor, you would have seen to it
>   that your poor brother attended the
>   bar mitzvah in new clothing. As it
>   occurred, he arrived in rags."
>
> So too, G-d promises to reimburse you
>   for what you spend for Shabbos and Yom
>   Tov; but only if you prove that you
>   are doing so to honor the Shabbos, by
>   providing for the needy and the poor
>   just as you do for yourself.

http://ohr.edu/ask/ask207.htm#PD

Comment: Thanks, R'Gershon Gold. Note that the parable and its referent are on the ohr.edu site, but were submitted thereto by an anonymous reader. Not to say it's incorrect.

Comment: R'msh210 - You are correct that this answer has no real source attached - although I do recall hearing this from a source, however can not remember who. However the first part of my answer definitvely shows that it applies to everything that is a Mitzva.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw the following in בית ומנוחה, a (Jerusalem, *Kislev* 5759) compilation by his son of speeches and letters of ר׳ משה אהרו שטרן, the late *mashgiach* of [Kamenitz](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A5), on page 137:

> זכורני שבירושלים היו נוהגים אנשי יראה, שהיו מרבים בקניות לצורך שבת, במדה כזאת שהיה נשאר לחצי השבוע הנוסף, באמרם הרי הוצאת שבת ויו״ט הם חוץ ממזונותיו הקצובים, א״כ למה לא נרבה כבר בהוצאה וישאר גם לימי החול, וכל זה היא בכלל הוצאת שבת ויו״ט. כשהיו צריכים לקנות נעליים לילד היו מחדשים ומלבישים את הנעליים לכבוד שבת, כדי שיהא חוץ ממזונותיו הקצובים

Or, in my own loose translation:

> I recall that, in Jerusalem, God-fearing men would purchase much for *Shabas*, a quantity that would allow leftovers for half the next week, saying "expenditures for *Shabas* and holidays are outside of one's allotment of livelihood, so why not spend more so that there'll be leftovers for the weekdays, and it will all count as expenditures for *Shabas* and holidays". When they needed to buy shoes for their children, they'd put the new shoes on the children for first time in honor of *Shabas*, so that it would be outside of one's allotment of livelihood

He cites this with approval. Several of my six subquestions seem to be (at least partially) answered by this. In order:

- At least for one's dependent children.
- Even shoes.
- [Not answered.]
- Even the weekday portion of stuff purchased for general use, as long as it was purchased with *Shabas* in mind and used for *Shabas*. (Or something like that.)
- Yes.
- Even if one bought extra so there'd be leftovers.